# Rails button_to with multiple line text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, button-to

I'm writing a Rails application and I have button that I create as follows:

```
<%= button_to t('.upload_html'), ... %>
```

where the ... stand for the other options. So the button should have the text pointed to by .upload_html and it does. Now I want that text to have two lines. In the YAML file I had

```
upload_html: "turn off"
```

and now I want

```
upload_html: "turn<br>off"
```

with a line break inside the button label text. But this does not work. It displays the string literally including the HTML tag without linebreaking. What can I do to force the line break?

Thank you!!
Best, Patrick

Comment: I've just discovered that if I change button_to to link_to, it works. So this must be a problem with button_to somehow ...

Comment: this is because your text is in <code>value</code> attribute. you cant insert multiline content in it. you can use link_to and style your link as button

Answer (score 0):

did you try `"turn<br>off".html_safe` ?

Comment: I just tried that. If I add this to the YAML file, I get a parser error. If I add it to the HTML file, nothing changes ...

Comment: how about `<%= button_to raw(t('.upload_html')), ... %>`?